how to disable auto logout when KVM-switch deselect current PC?
Desktop Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I have a KVM switch with monitor+mouse+keyboard connected to my desktop under Ubuntu (pc1) and my laptop under Windows (pc2). When I switch back to pc1 after working on pc2 for a short time, I find the lock screen and I have to enter the password, and my session resets, all my applications close. It happens over and over again. How can I forcibly disable it?
My settings:

settings -> privacy & security -> automatic screen lock (disabled)
settings -> privacy & security -> blank screen delay (never)
settings -> privacy & security -> lock screen on suspend (disabled)
settings -> power -> screen blank (never)
settings -> power -> automatic suspend (off)

Any other options to try?
I remember that using the same kvm switch on KDE, I did not encounter such a problem
